# How to run Aptitude's TUI with limit pattern sent as an argument?

Tags: debian, aptitude

I want to have a command on Debian (Sid) that launches aptitude's TUI with a limit pattern defined within the command itself as an argument.

Otherwise I have to write the pattern every time by pressing `l` in Aptitude's TUI and then searching for an online manual in order to know how to write these patterns.

The basic command I use to launch Aptitude:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e sudo aptitude
```

A limit pattern I want to add as an argument:

```
?tag(toolkit::qt)
```

In this case I want to launch Aptitude showing me all the Qt applications without having to input this pattern manually every time Aptitude launches.

I looked up Aptitude's man-pages, but I couldn't find the option for such argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no clean way to do this. This kludge seems to work, with well-behaved x-terminal-emulators.
(Apparently qterminal isn't one of those, i just discovered. I'll look to see if there is a corresponding bugreport. (Edit: [There is](https://github.com/lxqt/qterminal/issues/335).))

```bsh
x-terminal-emulator -e sh -c 'sudo -v ; { echo "l?tag(toolkit::qt)"; cat; } |sudo aptitude'
```

- The `sudo -v` is needed so the second `sudo` doesn't consume `echo`'s output.
- The `echo` starts with `l` to select the correct option from the menu.
- The `cat` allows interacting with `aptitude` after `echo` has finished.

Comment: I tested it right now with Alacritty and it works like a charm. Thanks!